# How do i upload two different files into a two different folders in nodejs by using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I want to upload two different files into two different folders 'uploads' and 'attachuploads' by using multer

My code Are given below

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, '../uploads');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname + '-' + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, ''));

      }
    });


var video   =   multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, '../attachuploads');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname + '-' + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, ''));

      }
    });

var upload = multer({ storage : storage, video : video });

/* Create Course */
router.post('/create', upload.any(),function(req, res, file) {

        var uploadpath =dirname+'/uploads/'+ req.files[0].originalname+ '-' + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
        var videopath =dirname+'/attachuploads/'+ req.files[0].originalname+ '-' + new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
        var courses = new Course({ 
            course_Name: req.body.coursename,
            course_Code: req.body.coursecode,
            course_Title: req.body.coursetitle,
            course_Author: req.body.courseauthor,
            course_Discription: req.body.coursediscription,
            course_Attachments: uploadpath,
            course_Video: videopath,
            course_Urlpath: req.body.courseurlpath,
            course_StartingDate: req.body.coursestartingdate,
            course_EndingDate: req.body.courseendingdate 
       });

        // save the sample course
        courses.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
            res.json({ success: true });

    });
});
```

using above code i can only upload to a single folder bt i want to upload into two differnt folders.please help me

Comment: is there any alternative way for this

Comment: not sure, but maybe you can try creating a middleware

Comment: i am new in nodejs .how could i create a middleware.